# How to check the date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format with the date present in 'Unix Time stamp' format in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, unix-timestamp

The table `event` has a column `start_time`, which holds the date in Unix Time stamp format.

Now I want to fetch all the records from the table whose date falls on the date given by user in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (like `2015-09-17`).

How should I do this using PHP? I can't use ready made MySQL functions for this.

Comment: Using `strtotime` function in PHP ? Or looking for DATE Format in MySQL.

Comment: The [`strtotime` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can convert the date to a Unix timestamp. Use the timestamp value when querying the MySQL table because you'll be comparing like to like, which is almost always faster - especially if you have an index on your `start_time` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?
What are your column names etc?

Having said that something like this

```
$date = new DateTime($userinputdate); // format: YYYY-MM-DD
$epoch_date = $date->format('U'); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `start_time`='$epoch_date'";
```

Sort your sql injection out use pdo/prepares and you should be fine.
I've not done the actual execution as you don't mention if you're using mysqli or PDO but that you should be able to work out yourself pretty easily

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've mentioned, table name, column name, etc. in my question. You can use them in your answer. So that I could accept your answer.

Comment: Have updated answer to show sql statement that will match your table details.

Answer (score 2):

You can user

> MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Function
>   or 
>   PHP DATE() Function

for formatting date.
MySql example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event.start_date, "%Y-%m-%d") FROM DB_NAME
```

PHP example:

```
$start_date = 1442838220; // Unix Timestamp
$formated = date('Y-m-d', $start_date); // YYYY-MM-DD format
```

Comment: I'm talking about PHP example. There I'm giving date in YYYY-MM-DD format and not in UNIX time stamp format. You are taking it as UNIX Time stamp format. Please make the necessary correction.

Comment: $start_date = 2015-09-21; 
$ formated = strtotime ($start_date);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$timestamp=1442838154;
echo date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE DATE(`start_time`) = CURDATE();
```